# How to Duplicate Records in the same MySQL Table Using the Inserted IDs

Tags: mysql, duplicates, last-insert-id

I have 2 tables. The first table is `tbl_items` and the second table is `tbl_items_extras`.

I insert my Items into `tbl_items` and if in case this item has a single/multiple extras, they will be inserted in the table `tbl_items_extras` where `tbl_items.id=tbl_items_extras.tbl_items_id`.

Below is the screenshot of my two tables. 
[image]

I was able to duplicate the records for `tbl_items` perfectly using the below query;

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_items` (`items_ref_id`, `rev`, `die_number`, `product_type_id`, `parts_id`, `complexity_id`)
          SELECT
            q.`items_ref_id`,
            q.`rev`+1,
            q.`die_number`,
            q.`product_type_id`,
            q.`parts_id`,
            q.`complexity_id`
          FROM `tbl_items` q WHERE `items_ref_id`='$refNum' AND `rev`='$maxRev'
```

But when I duplicate the `tbl_items_extras` records using the below query;

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_items_extras` (`tbl_items_id`, `extras_conditions_id`, `percentage`, `quantity`, `total_percentage`)
          SELECT
            q.`tbl_items_id`,
            q.`extras_conditions_id`,
            q.`percentage`,
            q.`quantity`,
            q.`total_percentage`
          FROM `tbl_items_extras` q WHERE `tbl_items_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_items` WHERE `items_ref_id`='$refNum' AND `rev`='$rev')
```

In this query, I didn't get what I need exactly. See the below screenshot.

[image]

What I need is to duplicate selected records in `tbl_items_extras` where the `tbl_items_id` has to be the `SQL_INSERTED_ID` of the duplicated records in `tbl_items`.

The result should be as per the below screenshot. 
[image]

As you can see, the `tbl_items.id` was used accordingly in the `tbl_items_extras.tbl_items_id`.

I know I can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID` but this works only for a single record.

Comment: You should use parameters instead of putting PHP variables directly into your query.

Comment: @Dharman, Thanks. But what do you mean by parameters?

Comment: You should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: quote_ref_id? Eh?

Comment: @Dharman, I'm already using these - `$refNum = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['refNum']);
$rev = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['rev']);`

Comment: Don't use these. They are not suitable for prevention of SQL injection and they only make your code messy and buggy. Use prepared statements with parameter binding, it will make your life much easier once you learn them.

Comment: Noted. Thanks @Dharman, I will learn from here. [link]https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Not the worst tutorial, but they still have some questionable code in there. Better learn from here: https://phpdelusions.net/

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.

I put my DUPLICATE QUERY inside a `WHILE LOOP` where I fetched the `id` of each row.

While `tbl_items` duplicates the record it will duplicate the `tbl_items_extras` using the fetched `id` and insert the `$inserted_tbl_items_id` in the `tbl_items_extras`.`tbl_items_id`.

```
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_items` WHERE `items_ref_id`= ? AND `rev`= ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $refNum, $maxRev);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // duplicate tbl_items
    if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id']; 

    // I put my tbl_items DUPLICATE QUERY (same as the above) 

    $inserted_tbl_items_id = $connect->insert_id; // get inserted id


    // and my tbl_items_extras DUPLICATE QUERY
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_items_extras` (`tbl_items_id`, `extras_conditions_id`, `percentage`, `quantity`, `total_percentage`)
      SELECT
        '$inserted_tbl_items_id',
        q.`extras_conditions_id`,
        q.`percentage`,
        q.`quantity`,
        q.`total_percentage`
      FROM `tbl_items_extras` q WHERE `tbl_items_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_items` WHERE `id`='$id')";
    $connect->query($sql);

    }
```